# Unitary equivalence of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, operator-algebras, matrix-analysis

Let $B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with $BB^*+B^*B=I$. Is $
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & B \\
B & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$ is unitarily similar to $
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \vert B\vert \\
\vert B^*\vert & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$ where $\vert A\vert=\sqrt{A^*A}$ for $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$?

**Comments**: I have been trying to prove the above question in the affirmative using the polar decomposition of $B$ but could not be successful yet. I also think $BB^*+B^*B=I$ may not be needed to prove the above question in the affirmative. Nevertheless, I include the condition in the question since I have it beforehand.

Any comment is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $B=U/\sqrt{2}$, where $U$ is unitary. 
Hence $BB^*+B^*B=Id$ and $|B|=|B^*|=Id/\sqrt{2}$. 
Thus,  your second matrix is Hermitian, but your first is not, if $B\neq B^*$. If a matrix is unitarily similar to an Hermitian matrix then the matrix must be Hermitian itself.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment on your question, the statement you are interested in is not generally true. However, you might be interested in the fact that the matrices
$$
\pmatrix{0 & B\\ B^* & 0}, \quad \pmatrix{0&|B|\\ |B| & 0}
$$
**are** necessarily unitarily similar. We note that $B$ has a polar decomposition of the form
$$
B = |B|U
$$
for some unitary matrix $U$.  With that, we can write
$$
\pmatrix{0&B\\B^*&0} = \pmatrix{0 & |B| U\\ U^*|B| & 0} =\\
\pmatrix{I & 0\\0 & U}^*\pmatrix{0 & |B|\\ |B| & 0}\pmatrix{I & 0\\0 & U}.
$$

Comment: This I observed. Anyway, thank you for your comments.